# Pandas Error Combining Conditions in Where Clause

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with binary flag values and I'm trying to clean it up if there are mistakes. A mistake would be if a particular group has both 0's and 1's. My rule is that this column can only contain either 0's or 1's within the group. I'm trying to come up with an np.where() clause such that I'm testing for groups with a column that has a single repeated value and also that the first value of that column in the group isn't 1. If the first value of the group isn't 1, and there's a mix of values, flip them all to 0 in that group.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where((df.groupby('CombBitSeq')['Flag'].transform('std') != 0) & (df.groupby('CombBitSeq')['Flag'].nth(0) != 1), 0, df['Flag'])
```

The error I'm getting is this, and I'm not sure how the lengths of the two combined conditions are off by 1:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (336661,) () (336660,)
```

Comment: Which is it that has one extra element?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the nth() condition

Comment: Try replacing that with `df.groupby('CombBitSeq')['Flag'].transform('head', 1)`

Comment: That seemed to work. If you move it below, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the first item per group and translate that throughout the entire dataframe, use `groupby` + `transform` + `head`, instead of `nth`:

```
df.groupby('CombBitSeq')['Flag'].transform('head', 1)
```

Your condition now becomes:

```
g = df.groupby('CombBitSeq')['Flag']    # let's compute this only once
df['Flag'] = np.where(
     g.transform('std').ne(0) & g.transform('head', 1).ne(1), 0, df['Flag']
)
```